# Is it a pattern of concurrent programming?

Tags: design-patterns, concurrent-programming

Some OOP design appeared in my head. It's like a pool and a factory.

The factory creates resources that can be shared between multiple threads.
One resource entity is expensive and its creation takes many time.
A resource can be used by multiple threads at one time.

In my particular case a resource is a SSH connection. SSH connection uses one TCP socket.
But one SSH connection can have multiple sessions.
Each thread creates new session for itself.
Session creation doesn't require to work with the factory.

Multiple threads can try to interact with the same remote host.

I defined statuses for a resource:

init  some thread tried to get SSH connection but it doesn't exists.
      there is a long process of resource creation. If another thread will try 
      to get the same resource too it gets that the required resource is on the progress
      and the second thread goes to wait a notification.

free  all sessions are closed and no thread uses the SSH connection

busy  at least one thread has taken the SSH connection

closed tcp socket is destroyed

There is a state diagram of a resource:

- -> init -> busy -> free -> closed

  free -> busy

I read books about OOP patterns, enterprise application patterns, concurrent patterns 
but I cannot remember a situation that I described above.

SSH is just example. This pattern fits to any heavy resource that supports 
concurrent work. When second thread wants to get creating resource but creation
second instance of resource is nonsense.

If it's a pattern then what's his name?
I confident this design is already described somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

As I got it, your have to solve the problem of an "connection pool".
and a connection pool is an implementation of an "pooling pattern".

The difference, to the pattern (what I see) is, that in your implementation the user of the session knows something about the mangling with the connection and the pooling-stuff.

For me a more "pattern way" seems, if the user orders a session from the session-pool and give it back to it. So the pooling system knows if there are connections needed, and the creation/destroy-mechanism is transparent to the user.
The user gets the "connection" because he has a session.

> Session creation doesn't require to work with the factory.

That maybe true, but the lifecycle of the session is vital to the lifecycle of the connection. So I would give the responsibility to create/destroy to the pool and not to the using objects.